# Wordpress redirect to another link

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain

At first i develop a `wordpress` site in my `sub-domain` `http://organicbeautycare.wp.digmark.info/`. Than i move all file in my main `domain` `http://organicbeautycare.ml/`. Now i delete my `sub-domain` in my `cpanel`. Now the problem is when i go to my main domain it's redirect me `http://organicbeautycare.wp.digmark.info/`in this `url`.

What should i do now? I tried many time it's. I edit my `detabase` site name also but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your database, Replace all the existence of old domain name with new domain name in the database & import again.

You need to save your permalinks again from wordpress admin. Also, in some cases you might need to set default menu & theme logo again

Comment: Yes its works well but my menu bar is not seen. i save again but not show this. http://organicbeautycare.ml/

Comment: you need to set your menu locations from wordpress backend from Appearance > Menus > Manage Locations